# Is there any way to fetch one to many relations with a single SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I'm fetching data from another table, using a record ID, I can do it like this:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` = 5");
$product = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$product_id = $product['id'];

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `product_images` WHERE `product_id` = $product_id");
$images = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$product['images'] = $images;
```

This is tedious, so maybe there's a better way to do this? Also, when you have multiple products, you have to do something like:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `products`");
$products = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($products as $productKey => $product){
    $product_id = $product['id'];

    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `product_images` WHERE `product_id` = $product_id");
    $images = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $products[$productKey]['images'] = $images;
}
```

Which is just as bad.

Comment: Why not use a `JOIN`?

Comment: Start here, with [A nice little tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Comment: @NicoHaase because there will be duplicates. Having an array with ten equal products that differ by one image is not overly efficient way of doing things

Comment: depends on the data that `product_images` store, if just link to image you can use join with `CONCAT()` function to have all images in one value and then just use `explode()` to get the array from that value

Comment: Actually your first attempt seems rather redundant anyway. If you know that `products.id = 5` then you dont need that query anyway as all you use of the result set is the `id` which I would hazzard a guess would be **5** :)

Comment: @nick there is nothing wrong with this method. you can slightly improve it by getting all the product ids using array_column and running a single query with IN() clause but in the end it will be quite the same.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - In the end, they are adding the images to the product array (from the first query) so I think they still need the first query to get the product data.

Comment: @El_Vanja This would not the the first query that used `*` when only one columns was actually required by the subsequent code :) But you are right I think

Comment: @FilipKováč it's only called GROUP_CONCAT() and yes it can be used but in the end there will be the same loop only with explode instead of a query.

Comment: @YourCommonSense yeah, there will be a loop, but without the select statement

Comment: It seems to me that there'd be remarkably little point to relational databases if they were unable to service this need in some way

Comment: @Strawberry that's where ORMs come to the rescue.

Comment: @YourCommonSense What is this heresy? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably not recommend creating such complex structures. However, I do recommend to avoid loops. What I would usually do is fetch all the records from images table grouped by `product_id` in PDO.

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT product_id, path, name, etc FROM `product_images`");
$images = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO:FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This will create a 3-dimensional array where the first level will be keyed with the first column `product_id`. You can then access it inside of the loop instead of making a select.

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT product_id, path, name, etc FROM `product_images`");
$images = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO:FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT id, product_name, etc FROM `products`");
$products = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($products as $product_id => $product) {
    $images = $images[$product_id] ?? [];
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Your approach is good for such an entity like categories but  the number of images is potentially infinite and one never selects all images or products. At least pagination is usually employed.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that this must appear terribly vulgar to the ORM brigade, but here's how we used to do it:

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] 
       c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually 
     , n.eed
  FROM products p
  JOIN product_images i 
     ON i.product_id = p.id 
 WHERE p.id = 5
```

As pointed out by others, in this particular case, this can probably be simplified as:

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] 
       c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually 
     , n.eed
  FROM product_images i 
 WHERE product_id = 5
```